# Google map transparent background html2canvas JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, html2canvas

I am printing a google map by using html2canvas to get the pdf of the map. I have disabled the background imagery and got the following pic [google map drawing tool to pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftNAN.png) in the pdf. What I am wondering about now is how to make the background color of the google map to be transparent or white in color?

What i have coded so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Drawing Tools</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha256-h20CPZ0QyXlBuAw7A+KluUYx/3pK+c7lYEpqLTlxjYQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }

    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .gm-style-cc {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 10px;">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" style='background-color:#2a3e42; color:white;text-align:center;'>
            <h6>Layers Selection</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <button class='btn btn-block' id="Canvas" onclick="takepicture()">Canvastopdf</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    // This example requires the Drawing library. Include the libraries=drawing
    // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
    // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=drawing">

    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {
                lat: -34.397,
                lng: 150.644
            },
            zoom: 8
        });

        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: ['marker', 'circle', 'polygon', 'polyline', 'rectangle']
            },
            markerOptions: {
                icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
            },
            circleOptions: {
                fillColor: '#ffff00',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 5,
                clickable: false,
                editable: true,
                zIndex: 1
            }
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
    }

    function takepicture() {
        document.querySelectorAll('[role="button"]').forEach(function (el) {
            el.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');

        });
        var node = document.querySelector('[title="Toggle fullscreen view"]');
        node.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');

        var node = document.querySelector('[title="Drag Pegman onto the map to open Street View"]');
        node.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');

        var node = document.querySelector('[title="Drag Pegman onto the map to open Street View"]');
        node.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');

        var node = document.querySelector('[title="Zoom in"]');
        node.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');

        var node = document.querySelector('[title="Zoom out"]');
        node.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');

        var el = document.getElementById('map');
        el.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';


        // node.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("map"), {
            background: '#fff',
            allowTaint: false,
            onrendered: function (canvas) {


                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                //var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0");
                var pdf = new jsPDF();
                pdf.addImage(img, 'png', 15, 20, 90, 90);
                pdf.save('a4.pdf')
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Google map drawing tools to canvas JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829740/google-map-drawing-tools-to-canvas-js)

Answer (score -1):

So by doing some digging i found the answer by changing the color of the  div with tab-index 0 to rgb(255,255,255). Here is the changed code for the function takepicture that will change the background color white

```
function takepicture()
{
 $(".gm-style>div:first>div:first>div:nth-child(2)>div:first>div").css("display:none;");
 document.querySelectorAll('[role="button"]').forEach(function (el) {
 el.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');

 });

document.querySelectorAll('[class="gm-style-pbc"]').forEach(function (el) {
    el.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');

});
document.querySelectorAll('[class="gm-style-cc"]').forEach(function (el) {
    el.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');

});

document.querySelectorAll('[class="gmnoprint"]').forEach(function (el) {
    el.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');

});


//var node = document.querySelector('[title="Toggle fullscreen view"]');
//node.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');
var a= document.getElementById("map").children[0]; console.log({a});
a.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';

$('div[tabindex=0]').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
document.querySelectorAll('[class="gm-style"]').forEach(function (el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
    console.log(el);

});
var node = document.querySelector('[title="Zoom in"]');
node.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');

var node = document.querySelector('[title="Zoom out"]');
node.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');

document.querySelectorAll('[class="gmnoprint gm-style-cc"]').forEach(function (el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';

});

var el = document.getElementById('map');
el.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';



// node.setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');
html2canvas(document.getElementById("map"), {
    background: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
    allowTaint: false,
    onrendered: function (canvas) {


        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        //var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0");
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(img, 'png', 15, 20, 180, 120);
        pdf.save('a4.pdf')
    }
});

}
```

Comment: This is prone to errors with the use of undocumented CSS selectors which could change at any time. Instead, you should change the map [style](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) and set all styles to `"color": "#ffffff"` which will achieve the same but with documented methods and which I suggested already on your [previous identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829740/google-map-drawing-tools-to-canvas-js).